# How to set the gradle outout folder for the kotlin2JS plugin?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have a KotlinJs only project which I use official kotlin2js gradle to build, and no problems there.

How to setup the output folder, currently, the building of subproject will result in a `build` which locates inside the subproject folder, how to set it to somewhere else? I tried:

```
sourceSets {
      main {
          kotlin.outputDir = new File(‘./out/‘)
      }
}
```

and

```
sourceSets {
      main.kotlin.outputDir = new File(‘./out/’)

}
```

No luck.

What I want is to no matter how many subprojects are there, the output folder should be in some path like `./build/projectA` and `./build/projectB`, rather than all in their own folder. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it's done through the task configuration, namely setting its `kotlinOptions.outputFile`:

```
compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions.outputFile = "out/output.js"
```

It's briefly mentioned in the tutorial: [Getting Started with Kotlin and JavaScript with Gradle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/getting-started-gradle/getting-started-with-gradle.html#configuring-compiler-options)